# How to change column datatype by refrencing other table which has column type details in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to change `df2` column datatype as mentioned in the `df1` column type details.

Example: `age` needs to change to an `int` and `salary` needs to change to a `float`.

`df1`:

```
  ColumnName ColumnType  
0 Name       string   
1 Age        int   
2 Emp_Id     string
3 salary     float
```

`df2`:

```
    Name   Age  salary  Emp_Id
0   Tom     20  1000    111
1   nick    21  2000    222
2   krish   19  4500    333
3   Tommy   18  6500    444
4   Andy    27  5666    555
5   rick    20  2866    666
```

`df2.dtypes`:

```
Name      object
Age       object
salary    object
Emp_Id    object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
for i,r in df1.iterrows():
  if r['ColumnType'] == 'string':
    r['ColumnType'] = 'str'
  df2[r['ColumnName']] = df2[r['ColumnName']].astype(r['ColumnType'])

df2.dtypes
```

Output:

```
Name       object
Age         int64
salary    float64
Emp_Id     object
dtype: object
```